# Find the closest checked checkbox value

Tags: php, jquery

I have a list of products with prices, before the productname I have a checkbox. What I want is when I checked a checkbox the price must show up in the table.

The products are fetched by a loop from MySQL.

This is my code for a better view:

```
<?
    $query = "SELECT upgrades.upgrade_name, upgrades.upgrade_id, upgrades.volgorde, upgrades.price
            FROM upgrades
            LEFT JOIN upgrades_to_products
            ON upgrades.upgrade_id = upgrades_to_products.upgrade_id
            WHERE upgrades_to_products.product_id = 20
            AND status = 1
            ORDER BY upgrades.volgorde";
    $sql = mysql_query("$query");
    while ($fill = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $upgrade_id = $fill['upgrade_id'];
        $upgrade_name = $fill['upgrade_name'];
        $price = $fill['price'];

        $name = str_replace(' ', '_', $upgrade_name);
        $name = strtolower($name);
        echo '
        <tr class="'.$class.'">                         
            <td>
                <input id="'.$name.'" name="'.$name.'" type="checkbox" value="'.$price.'" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="http://www.informer.nl/modules/?ID='.$_GET['ID'].'&upgrade_id='.$upgrade_id.'" target="_blank">'.$upgrade_name.'</a>
                <a href="http://www.informer.nl/modules/?ID='.$_GET['ID'].'&upgrade_id='.$upgrade_id.'" target="_blank">
                    <img src="images/vraag.jpg" border="0" style="margin-left:5px;" />
                </a>
            </td>
            <td align="right">&euro; '.sprintf('%01.2f', $price).'</td>                         
            <td align="right"><div class="module_value"></div></td>                         
        </tr>';
    }
?>
```

You can see the checkbox between the first `<td></td>`. So when I checked one of the checkboxes that value must show up in the `<div class="module_value"></div>`.

I tried something like this:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {
    var module_price = $("input[type=checkbox]").val();
    $(".module_value").text(module_price.toFixed(2));
});
```

but that didnt work so I hope someone can help me out.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`:checkbox`](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) selector for accesing checkboxes and [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) would be a better choice for your job. With [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) you can find parent `tr` element and then you can find `.module_value` from there and change it's text.

```
$(':checkbox').change(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        $tr = $this.closest('tr');
    $tr.find('.module_value').text(this.checked ? $this.val() : '');
});
```

You can see it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gZrgd/1/).

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked. The only problem now is when I uncheck a box the price still shows.

Comment: Fixed: $(':checkbox').change(function() {
   if(this.checked) {
    var $this = $(this),
     $tr = $this.closest('tr');
    $tr.find('.module_value').text($this.val());
   }
   else
   {
    var $this = $(this),
     $tr = $this.closest('tr');
    $tr.find('.module_value').text('');
   }
  });

Comment: One little question, how can i get this notation 1.200,95 instead of this 1200.9500

Comment: Use [`number_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) instead of `sprintf`

Comment: Yes thank you, this is for PHP but for the prices in javascript?

Comment: There is no internal format number script like PHP for Javascript. Maybe `.toFixed()`. You can search web for javascript number formatting functions.